# How do I make a saving death counter leaderstats

Tags: roblox

So I am trying to make a game, but cant keep the stats. I already have a working death counter but can't figure out how to save it, it resets everytime I rejoin. Here are two codes I've tried:

1)

```
local pointsDataStore = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("Deaths")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local playerKey = "Player_" .. player.UserId

    local success, err = pcall(function()
        pointsDataStore:UpdateAsync(playerKey, function(oldValue)
            local newValue = oldValue or 0
            newValue = newValue + 0
            return newValue
        end)
    end)
end)
```

2)

```
local DS = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("Points")

game.Player.PlayerAdded:connect(plr)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Model",plr)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local currency = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    currency.Name = "Deaths"
    currency.Value = 1

   while wait(5) do
    DS:SetAsync(plr.userId.."_DS", currency.Value)
  end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would load the value from a datastore when the player joins, then increment it on each death and also save it to the datastore.

Note, that for triggering death, the script is using the [Humanoid.Died](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Humanoid/Died) event.

```
local deathsStore = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("Deaths")

function playerAddedHandler(plr)  
    -- key that is used to store the death value
    local playerKey = "Player_" .. plr.UserId 

    -- Add leader board
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", plr)  
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

    -- Add "Deaths" column to leader board 
    local deaths = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    deaths.Name = "Deaths"

    -- Load Deaths value from previous game
    deaths.Value = deathsStore:GetAsync(playerKey) 

    -- Hook up event handler that is triggered when character dies
    plr.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        char.Humanoid.Died:Connect(function()

            -- increment death value on the leader board
            plr.leaderstats.Deaths.Value = plr.leaderstats.Deaths.Value + 1

            -- save the value in our deaths datastore
            local success, err = pcall(function()
                deathsStore:SetAsync(playerKey, plr.leaderstats.Deaths.Value)
            end)    
        end)
    end)
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(playerAddedHandler) -- call function "playerAddedHandler" every time a player joins the game
```

Also. Don't forget to enable datastore usage, otherwise it will give you a 403 error in your output. You do that on the roblox website in your game's basic settings:

[image]